# Stored procedure to duplicate master detail data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am new stored procedures and trying to write a procedure to duplicate user(by user_id) master detail data into a new user data. Here is my table structure. I will pass a target user_id and destination user_id to the stored procedure. Could you please let me know the how to achieve this functionality? I appreciate any help.

```
TABLE A
----------------
a_id       int(Primary Key)  
desc       varchar(50)
user_id    int

TABLE B
-----------------
b_id       int(Primary Key)
a_id       int(Foreign Key)
detail     varchar(100)

CREATE PROCEDURE [duplicate_user_data] 
    @old_user_id int,
    @new_user_id int
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TABLEA
           ([desc]
           ,[user_id]
           )
    select desc, user_id from TABLEA where user_id = @old_user_id
END
```

Comment: after your insert, capture scope_identity() into a local variable, then insert a select of the tableB using the local variable in the a_id column.

Comment: How can I get scope_identity() for multiple records from TABLEA?

Comment: if you have multiple, then use `OUTPUT INTO`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a self-join to match the old and new parent ids.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [duplicate_user_data] 
    @old_user_id int,
    @new_user_id int
AS
    INSERT INTO TableA ([desc], [user_id])
    SELECT [desc], @new_user_id
    FROM TableA
    WHERE [user_id] = @old_user_id

    INSERT INTO TableB ([a_id], [detail])
    SELECT NewTableA.[a_id], TableB.[detail]
    FROM TableA AS NewTableA
    CROSS JOIN TableA AS OldTableA
    JOIN TableB ON TableB.[a_id] = OldTableA.[a_id]
    WHERE NewTableA.[user_id] = @new_user_id
    AND OldTableA.[user_id] = @old_user_id
```

Comment: There are 13 records in my TABLE B table. But I am getting 37752 rows using the CROSS JOIN query.

Comment: Wow, that is unexpected. Does your WHERE clause really contain both user_id variables? Also, my answer assumes there is a UNIQUE constraint on [user_id] for TableA. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, user_id is unique. Now I used both user_id variables but it returns 66 records this time.

Answer (score 0):

if I am understanding you correctly, you want to insert a new record for the new user but copy the details from another user.  If so, then you can do something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [duplicate_user_data] 
    @old_user_id int,
    @new_user_id int
AS
BEGIN
    declare @old_a_id int

    -- get the old a_id first
    SELECT @old_a_id = a_id
    FROM TableA
    WHERE [user_id] = @old_user_id

    -- insert the new record into TableA
    INSERT INTO TABLEA
    (
        [desc]
        ,[user_id]
    )
    select [desc]
        , @new_user_id 
    from TABLEA 
    where [user_id] = @old_user_id

    -- insert new record into tableB using the @old_a_id 
    INSERT INTO TableB
    (
        a_id
        , detail
    )
    SELECT @old_a_id
        , detail
    FROM TableB
    WHERE a_id = @old_a_id
END
```

This will then insert your `new_user_id` into `TableA` but will have the `[desc]` from your `old_user_id`

Comment: Thank you. How can I copy TABLE B data?

Comment: what are you trying to do with TableB?  your OP is not clear.

Comment: I have to get old a_id from TABLEA and query TABLEB and duplicate.

Comment: Do I have to loop through the records from Table A and insert into TABLE A and TABLE B?

Comment: based on your question, you are inserting one new id at a time, so there shouldn't be a need to loop

Comment: TABLE A has 3 records for old_user_id and TABLE B has 10 records for each record from TABLE A.